# Laravel 5.6 как проверить авторизирован ли пользователь на сайте когда отправляет запрос через API

Tags: laravel

Подскажите пожалуйста, как в Laravel 5.6 можно проверить авторизирован ли пользователь на сайте когда отправляет запрос через API? То есть нужно до того как auth:api авторизирует пользователя по токену проверить авторизирован ли он на сайте.

Comment: Может я не понял вопроса, но смысл авторизации по токену и есть в том, чтобы понять авторизован пользователь или нет. В токене есть необходимая информация, которую расшифровывает API и делает соотвествующие выводы

Comment: Нужно проверить что только авторизированный пользователь отправляет запрос на определенные маршруты если это так то далее "auth:api" должен авторизировать его. Нужно убедиться что у него есть сессия и на сайте и токен который он прислал валидный.

Comment: мне кажется вы не совсем понимаете назначение api интерфейса

Comment: Все это делает авторизация по токену, OAuth2 и ему подобные протоколы. Если Вы спрашиваете как это реализовать на Laravel, то в интернете полно статей на эту тему.

Comment: API служит для доступа к данным из любого приложения, авторизация по токену. Но если вам нужно обрабатывать запросы с учетом пользователя - используйте роуты, отличные от `/api/**`, где есть группа посредников web. Там можете узнать пользователя по `\Auth::user()`

Comment: для примера: "auth:api" проверит токен который прислал пользователь, правильно? (например если я через постман отправляю валидный токен - это сработает), но нужно еще дополнительно проверить отправил ли это пользователь который авторизирован на сайте.

Comment: Если пользователь имеет валидный токен, это и есть гарантия того, что он авторизован.

Comment: да, но нужно убедиться что он авторизирован на сайте так как доступ к некоторым маршрутам имеет только авторизированный пользователь. Если он не авторизирован на сайте и постучался по ендпоинту нужно отказать ему в доступе еще до проверки токена.